# External monitor connected via USB-C → HDMI/VGA/2xUSB dongle doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, usb-c

I work on Lenovo Ideapad, Ubuntu 18.04. I have one external monitor working fine on HDMI. I'd like to add the second monitor via USB-C → HDMI/VGA/2xUSB dongle but it is not detected. The dongle works fine on Windows and on Ubuntu I checked that with USB device (USB -> USB-C). 
Result of `lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

result of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

also when I run `dmesg -wH` and plug/unplug monitor via usb-c it shows exactly nothing.

Could you help?

Comment: Did you make sure that the USB-C port on your Ideapad supports video out?  Not all USB-C ports are the same.

Comment: @Terrance how can I check that? I was pretty sure that the last two lines from lsusb -t output say that?

Comment: the model is 530S-14IKB, also I have only one USB-C port

Comment: What is your USB-C to video dongle?  Sorry, I missed the part of you stating that it works with Windows.

Comment: I don't know. It has no model on it indicated :/ It works well for usb and for Windows. But I think it actually might be lenovo hardware problem, not software.
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx/320-15IKB-USB-Type-C-to-HDMI-not-working/td-p/3934383?page=1

Comment: It could be a hardware problem.  Or it could be a kernel / chip set incompatibility.  I am trying to remember how I found it but my Ubuntu 18.04 installation when I replaced my MSI MS-7508 to a Gigabyte GA-78LMT-USB3 and the USB 3.0 port on it had an issue when i would plug in an external drive, but yet it worked absolutely fine in Windows.  It too was showing as a xhci_hcd port.  Luckily I was able to add my old USB 3 card back to this motherboard that I knew worked and now it is fine in both Windows and Ubuntu.  Maybe Lenovo might make a driver for their chip set.

Comment: Thank you for your time!